Proof Verification - $n$th non square number
I was trying to derive an expression for the $n$th non square number. Could someone verify if my proof is on the right track?
The $n$th non-square number must lie between two consecutive square numbers, say: $a^2 $ and $(a+1)^2$.
Let $c_n$ be the $n$th non square number.
$\implies c_n = a^2 + k ~|~0 \le k \le 2a , k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
(As the spacing between $a^2$ and $(a+1)^2$ is $2a$)
There are $a^2-a$ non square numbers before $a^2$
$\implies n = a^2-a+k ~~|~~ 0 \le k \le 2a , k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
$\implies a^2-a+(k-n)=0$ which is a quadratic equation in $a$

Doubtful step
Since for a given $n, ~k$ is fixed and there must exist only a single value of $a$
$\therefore D = 1 - 4(k-n) = 0 \implies k = \dfrac {1}{4}$ which does not make sense as $k$ is an integer.

EDIT
Through the discussion below, the above step was found to be false. By the quadratic formula, $a$ can be found out as:
$\therefore a = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4(n-k)}}{2}$
$\implies 4 a^2 = 1 + 1 + 4(n-k) + 2 \sqrt {1+4(n-k)}$
$\implies 4 a^2 = 1 + 1 + 4(n-k) + 2 \sqrt {1+4(n-k)}$
$\implies 4 (a^2 + k ) = 1 + 1 + 4(n-k) + 2 \sqrt {1+4(n-k)} + 4k$
$\implies 4 c_n = 2 + 4n + 2 \sqrt {1+4(n-k)}$
$\implies c_n = n + \dfrac {1+ \sqrt {1+4(n-k)}}{2}$
How do I prove that this is equal to $a(n) = n + \Big\lfloor \frac 12 + \sqrt n\Big\rfloor$?

One error is here: There are $a^2-a$ non square numbers before $a$ - No. For, say,  $a=4$, you claim that there are $16-4=12$ non squares before $4$. But there are only the non-squares $2$ and $3$ before $4$.

Although the error is rather apparent, I don't understand the downvote / vote to close. Details and attempts have been provided.

@DietrichBurde I have edited it to make it there are $a^2-a$ non square numbers before $a^2$

@AlvinL Thank you for your comment. I have edited it to state that there are $a^2-a$ non square numbers before $a^2$. Is there still an error?

Related, and the many posts linked to it.

@AnneBauval I did see those posts; I am trying to find the error in my attempt here though; I haven't followed my attempt on those lines

"there must exist only a single value of $a$" such that $a^2<c_n<(a+1)^2$, but there may be another one satisfying the quadratic equation. For instance if $n=1$ or $2$ then $k=n$ and $a=1$ but the other root of $a^2-a+0=0$ is $a=0$.

For example, $c_{11}=14=3^2+5$, results in the equation $a^2-a-6=0$ which is satisfied by $a=3$ but does not have a zero determinant. Its other root is $a=-2$, which is not a relevant solution to this problem. Just because you want a single relevant (i.e. positive) solution, this does not imply that the determinant is zero.

Personally, I disagree with both the (still existing) single vote to close, and any downvote that this posted question received.  However, I feel that the original poster is entitled to an explanation why other MathSE reviewers have reacted negatively to this posted question.  ...see next comment

(Same feelings, except that I cannot see any other negative reaction than the vote to close and downvote.) @Jaap discriminant.

"For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so." : The quoted excerpt explains the intended use of the solution-verification tag.  I would speculate, perhaps inaccurately, that at the time of the negative reaction, a reviewer (perhaps incorrectly) felt that the posted question was not focusing directly on a specific step.  ...see next comment

@mathman I considered your initial mixup a typo. A serious problem is already pointed out as well. You have assumed that the resulting quadratic must have vertex on the $x$-axis. In actuality, by uniqueness you mean that you are not interested in negative solutions.

Personally, I have never been comfortable with this narrow interpretation of the appropriate use of the solution-verification tag, or the corresponding negative reactions by MathSE reviewers to questions that violate this narrow interpretation.  However, the narrow definition exists, and the negative reactions exist.  So, at least now, the original poster has some explanation as to what may have occurred, and the original poster may or may not use this explanation to guide their thinking, when composing future questions on MathSE.

Clarification : Other comments have presumably indicated analytical errors in your posted work.  With respect to determining whether your posted question is appropriate for MathSE, the existence of analytical errors is not a basis for any negative reaction from MathSE reviewers, re a downvote or vote-to-close.  In fact, such analytical errors are to be expected in (even) high quality MathSE posted questions.

The OP correctly sensed the ballpark where his mistake was, hence I am of the opinion the verification tag is justified.

With your latest fix, the last "$\implies$" is a long way of writing $c_n = n+a$.

@AnneBauval Thank you very much!

@JaapScherphuis Thank you very much!

@AlvinL Thank you very much!

@user2661923 Thank you very much for those comments!

Your final question is: How do I prove that
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(n-k)}}2=\Big\lfloor \frac 12 + \sqrt n\Big\rfloor?$$
Well, you already know that the LHS is the positive integer $a$, so you only need to  check that $a\le \frac 12 + \sqrt n<a+1$, i.e. that
$$\left(a-\frac12\right)^2\le n<\left(a+\frac12\right)^2,$$
or equivalently, that
$$a^2-a+\frac14\le a^2-a+k<a^2+a+\frac14.$$
This stems from $1\le k\le2a$.

(With the risk of this question being too similar to the previous question, or worse, needing clarification)
Using the range of $k$ relative to $a$ (which originates from the range of $c_n$), and $n = a^2-a+k$,
$$\begin{align*}
a^2+1 \le c_n &\le (a+1)^2 -1\\
1 \le k &\le 2a\\
a^2 -a+1 \le n &\le a^2 -a + 2a\\
a^2-a+\frac14 < n &< a^2 + a + \frac14\\
a-\frac12 < \sqrt n &< a+\frac12\\
a < \frac12 + \sqrt n &< a+1\\
\left\lfloor \frac12 + \sqrt n \right\rfloor &= a
\end{align*}$$
Then with your latest approach,
$$\begin{align*}
c_n = a^2+k
= \ldots
&= n+a\\
&= n+\left\lfloor \frac12 + \sqrt n \right\rfloor
\end{align*}$$

Thank you$~~~~~~~$!
